# What's the meaning of the snippet of dialogue at the beginning of "All the Pretty Girls?"

Tags: lyrics, indie

The song "All the Pretty Girls" by fun. starts with a short snippet of dialogue that sounds like

> [indecipherable talking]
>
> (So it's?) gonna have to be two passes.
>
> The pretty... [actual song begins]

This part isn't [on the official music video's version](https://youtu.be/AIoaiTwLk6I), but it is on [the Spotify version](https://open.spotify.com/track/1TQyRzRnGJflBhUHAwtk1x) of the song.

Is it known what exactly they're saying or what it refers to?

Comment: Could be it studio talk about the recording, like  Bob Dylan's "Is it rolling, Bob?" (spoken to producer Bob Johnston) at the start of "To be alone with You".  that would fit with it being on the SoundCloud version only

Answer (score 1):

I have found no references of this, and as you said it appears on the Spotify version, not in the youtube version.

Its is probably unwanted studio talk.

> *Someone in the back*: **Yeah, let's go**.
>   *Another guy*: **So it's gonna have to be two passes**.
>   *Another dude*: **The pretty...**

Or maybe it is intentional, like if someone recorded a mixtape and there were still parts of the former recording that remained in the beginning of the tape.